# Haacked JQuery Undoable "Object doesn't support this property"

Tags: jquery, javascript, undo

I refer to Phil Haack's "Undoable" article found here: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/01/jquery-undoable-plugin.aspx

I've copied the exact mark-up for the table from the tables demo page, included JQuery 1.3.2 min, and copied the exact script block used on the demo page but when it gets to this bit:

```
$('a.delete').undoable({
 inlineStyling: false,
 showingStatus: function(undoable) {
```

I keep getting "Object doesn't support this property or method". Is there anything obvious that I might be missing to cause that? I'm just using IE8 on the dev machine but that shouldn't be a problem (I hope).

Comment: have you tried in Firefox (with Firebug enabled)?  I'm wondering if maybe the error is somewhere else other than the code you pasted on SO

Comment: Can you post the order of your script tags, or script tags and in-line code if the above code is in the page?

Comment: please show the rest of the java code... it could be a problem that happened after the line shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this version (and look through the code for similar un-apostrophed JSONs).

```
$('a.delete').undoable({
 'inlineStyling': false,
 'showingStatus': function(undoable) {
```

Answer (score 1):

"Object doesn't support this property or method" may imply that your link to the jQuery library is invalid. Can you verify that jquery is actually being loaded maybe with a simple alert like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){alert("loaded")});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps loading the javascript files from the file system? This could fail in Internet Explorer due to security restrictions. From what you are saying it could be that you are loading jquery fine, but not the plug-in. Try to load both files from the site, as another commenter suggested.

There is no problem with the plug-in. I've tested it both in Firefox and IE 7 and it works. So the problem is of the javascript libraries failing to load for some reason.

Comment: IE does have issues with executing scripts from local storage. (for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Vincent's response - make sure you're adding [jquery.undoable.js](http://demo.haacked.com/jquery.undoable/src/jquery.undoable.js) file to your page

Comment: I've even resorted to linking directly to the file on his site used in the example to make sure it's getting the same file, same contents etc...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include your own .js script AFTER you include the JQuery library script

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the '$' symbol isn't bound to the jQuery object.  Does replacing '$' with 'jQuery' work?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('a.delete').ready(function() { this.undoable({
 inlineStyling: false,
 showingStatus: function(undoable) {
}}
```

also, the sample code actually looks like this, did you try just this code? (He said it does not have a backend in the sample...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.undoable.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    /* 
        Enables undoable operations
    */
    $(function() {
        $('a.delete').undoable();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual code defining `undoable` is not in the example on the page, and not part of jQuery. I think you forgot to include the library itself.

You can get that here:
http://github.com/Haacked/jquery.undoable/blob/master/src/jquery.undoable.js

Comment: No, I definitely included it. It is on the example page, I copied the include jquery.undoable line from the page source to make sure what I was using matched the actual running example.